# Find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\frac {\tan{\theta \over 2^n}}{2^{n-1} \cos{\theta \over 2^{n-1}}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I tried multiple ways to firstly simplify the question, sharing them :

1. Can I take the above sum equivalent to $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{1}^{n}\frac {\tan{\theta \over 2^n}}{2^{n-1} \cos{\theta \over 2^{n-1}}}d\theta$$?
   If I do this way, consequently its just the integral test to check for the convergence or divergence.So it won't seems right if I want to find the sum!
2. Using $\tan\theta$ = $\sin{\theta}\over \cos{\theta}$, to simplify the numerator didn't help.
3. Tried to plug in some inequalities, I am complexifying the things.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\dfrac{\tan t}{\cos2t}=\dfrac{\sin(2t-t)}{\cos t\cos2t}=\tan2t-\tan t$$